# Need Help In Creating Yii2 ActionForm

Tags: yii2

This is how I would like it to be displayed:-

```
<form action="?r=site/abc" method="POST">
  <input name="url" type="text" class="txt-fld_" placeholder="Enter the website">
  <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn-" value="Check it now">
</form>
```

And currently, I've done this:-

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
            [                                        
                'action' => ['?r=site/abc']
            ]
    );?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I know I can use this line to generate text fields:-

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'url') ?>
```

But there is no model involved. Just a simple form that sends a url to the abc action. Also how can I generate the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you don't need the model for anything else, you should still have one for your data, so that the form will perform validation. You can get it to check that a valid url is submitted, and prevent malicious attacks. It only needs to be a simple model. Once you have a model, then you can use all the features of Activeform to generate fields.

The submit button can be generated using [Html::submitButton()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#submitButton()-detail)